# how to build dogecoin CLI wallet

Tags: installation, apt, compiling, make, bitcoin

I'm trying to install dogecoin wallet, which depends on:

```
 Library Purpose Description
 ------- ------- -----------
 libssl SSL Support Secure communications
 libdb4.8 Berkeley DB Blockchain & wallet storage
 libboost Boost C++ Library
 miniupnpc UPnP Support Optional firewall-jumping support
 libqrencode QRCode generation Optional QRCode generation
```

https://github.com/dogecoin/dogecoin/blob/master/doc/build-unix.txt

I was having trouble with `boost`, but installed `libboost1.48-all-dev` and now get a simpler error message:

```
thufir@dur:~/dogecoin/src$ 
thufir@dur:~/dogecoin/src$ make -j2 -f makefile.unix USE_UPNP=-
/bin/sh ../share/genbuild.sh obj/build.h
g++ -c -O2 -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Wformat -Wformat-security -Wno-unused-parameter -g -DUSE_IPV6 -DBOOST_SPIRIT_THREADSAFE -I/home/thufir/dogecoin/src -I/home/thufir/dogecoin/src/obj -DHAVE_BUILD_INFO -fno-stack-protector -fstack-protector-all -Wstack-protector -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2  -MMD -MF obj/checkpoints.d -o obj/checkpoints.o checkpoints.cpp
g++ -c -O2 -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Wformat -Wformat-security -Wno-unused-parameter -g -DUSE_IPV6 -DBOOST_SPIRIT_THREADSAFE -I/home/thufir/dogecoin/src -I/home/thufir/dogecoin/src/obj -DHAVE_BUILD_INFO -fno-stack-protector -fstack-protector-all -Wstack-protector -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2  -MMD -MF obj/netbase.d -o obj/netbase.o netbase.cpp
In file included from main.h:14:0,
                 from checkpoints.cpp:12:
db.h:15:20: fatal error: db_cxx.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [obj/checkpoints.o] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
thufir@dur:~/dogecoin/src$
```

I'm not exactly sure what's not working there.  I'll look into `db_cxx.h`, which, presumably, is a `C` file?

Comment: see also http://b.agilob.net/such-address-many-dig-on-linux-wow/

Comment: see also  http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/1449/when-building-bitcoind-i-receive-error-headers-h3620-fatal-error-db-cxx-h

Answer (score 1):

Try

> sudo apt-get install libboost1.48-all-dev

Then

> make -j2 -f makefile.unix USE_UPNP=-

if you're making the daemon version. The USE_UPNP=- nullifies the need to install miniupnpc. As far as libqrencode, that is option as well.

Comment: this plus http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/10450/10651  `libdb++-dev`  seems to be compiling.  we'll see.

Comment: I think it finished                                         `-l db_cxx -l ssl -l crypto -Wl,-Bdynamic -l z -l dl -l pthread
thufir@dur:~/dogecoin/src$`

Answer (score 0):

I had an error compiling as well:

```
make: *** [build/main.o] Error 1
```

What resolved this for me was:

- remove the gitted folder including the write-protected git
- re-git the wallet

  git clone https://github.com/dogecoin/dogecoin.git
- then
  sudo apt-get install libboost1.48-all-dev

and the rest is as usuall